# Override subdirectory gitignore's "must include" rule with local .git/info/exclude

Tags: git, gitignore

Suppose I have the following git repository structure

```
> tree -a
.
├── .git
│   ├── info
│   │   └── exclude
└── a
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── mustinclude.txt
    └── my-local-file-to-ignore.txt
```

And the gitignore file says to always track txt files

```
> cat a/.gitignore
*
!*.txt
```

Is it possible to configure git so that it will ignore `a/my-local-file-to-ignore.txt` just for myself? The motivation for this is I want to include local scratch files (for testing or whatever) but I don't want other people using the repository to know about the existence of such a file.

I have tried putting that file in the info/exclude file but it doesn't work. I think this is because the gitignore file in a specifies to always include txt file.

```
> cat .git/info/exclude
a/my-local-file-to-ignore.txt
```

```
> git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   mustinclude.txt
    new file:   my-local-file-to-ignore.txt
```

Comment: Yes, [the gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) says that the `.gitignore` file in a directory overrides the `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` file directives.

Comment: @torek thanks for the link. After reading it, I feel that patterns in the `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` should be treated with higher precedence than .gitignore because it relates to the individual's workflow.

Answer (score 1):

`.gitignore` has a higher priority over `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`.

> Git normally checks `gitignore` patterns from multiple sources, with the following **order of precedence**, from **highest to lowest** (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the outcome):
>
> - Patterns read from the command line for those commands that support them.
> - Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file. A project normally includes such `.gitignore` files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.
> - Patterns read from `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`.
> - Patterns read from the file specified by the configuration variable `core.excludesFile`.

According to `gitignore` manual. `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` is the file you should use when you wanna ignore files locally for yourself only. The problem is that the patterns in your `a/.gitignore` overmatch.

To achieve what your want, you need to remove the global ignore patter `*` from `a/.gitignore` and ignore ONLY those files you don't want.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to achieve this without having to modify the checked in `.gitignore` file. To give a little more colour to my question. I work on a monorepo and the existing `.gitignore` file has a similar pattern in this question so that any new directories created in a folder will always be included. However, it would be easier for me to test my changes if I could insert my own testing/scratch subdirectory (think python or go). These testing code should only be visible by me so I want to overwrite the ignore rules. In any case, It is clear from the doc it is not a supported use case.