# Ignore a specific file in resource directory

Tags: gitignore

This is my .gitignore file:

```
HELP.md
tmp/
target/
!**/src/main/**
!**/src/test/**
```

How can I exclude only this file:

```
src/main/resources/application.properties
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fairly easy:

```
HELP.md
tmp/
target/
!**/src/main/**
!**/src/test/**
src/main/resources/application.properties
```

should work.

In case it doesn't, as it appears to be your case<sup>1</sup>, git allows you to ignore files, but remember this is a *local setting* and it *will not be pushed* to any other repository: go to `.git/info/exclude` and edit the file. It works like `.gitignore`.

Also remember: `.gitignore` has an higher priority on your `info/exclude` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218550/override-subdirectory-gitignores-must-include-rule-with-local-git-info-exclu)).

---

<sub>1. *this might be due to the fact that you have multiple* `.gitignore` *files in your directory, and thus there is overmatching of patterns.*</sub>

Comment: Thank you Daemon. Yep, that's what I was also assuming but not sure why it's not working. Strange

Comment: on my machine, this works. If on yours it does not, maybe check the order of ignore (is it included again after?) and/or the local exclude setting, in .git/info/exclude

Comment: Thank you. git/info/exclude did the job

Comment: Thank you Daemon