# Git gitignore undos the ./git/info/exclude files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a conflict between gitignore and ./git/info/exclude.

Folder content

```
.git
.gitignore   
test_file.txt
```

./git/info/exclude

```
test_file.txt
```

.gitignore

```
*
!*.txt
```

git status

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        test_file.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I know that the problem is in .gitignore, and .git/info/exlude executes before .gitignore. But if I add the `test_file.txt` after `!*.txt`, it will work. How do I can solve that without changing .giignore file? How to tell git to apply .git/info/exclude after .gitignore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58255189/7976758 "*.gitignore has a higher priority over $GIT_DIR/info/exclude.*" "*To achieve what your want, you need to remove the global ignore patter `*` from `.gitignore` and ignore ONLY those files you don't want.*" Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+%22info%2Fexclude%22

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the problem is in .gitignore, and .git/info/exlude executes before .gitignore.

That is not correct.
According to https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore first command line arguments are checked, then the `.gitignore` files, then `.git/info/exclude`, then the global excludes file.

But as soon as one of the options has a match for the path, no further options are checked and within the file that has a match the last matching entry is considered.

So as far as I can tell, there is no way to do what you intend to as the path is already matched by the `.gitignore` file. You would need to make the `.gitignore` file of the project less aggressive (matching `*`) to have a chance for `.git/info/exclude` to have an effect.